# Delphi - Como atribuir dados em um array multidimensional num só comando?

Tags: delphi

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte mas não está dando certo:

```
Var
  MyArray: array[1..3] of array[1..3] of Ttime;
Begin
   MyArray:=( ( StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:50') ),
              ( StrToTime('09:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25') ),
              ( StrToTime('10:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25') )
            );
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Achei uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479963/3722111) no SOen referente a pergunta [Pass a multidimensional array as a parameter in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780155/pass-a-multidimensional-array-as-a-parameter-in-delphi)

Convertendo para seu caso ficaria algo como:

```
type
  TMatrix = array[1..3,1..3] of Ttime;
```

---

```
procedure  MakeMat(var c: TMatrix; nr, nc: integer; a: array of Ttime);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  //SetLength(c, nr, nc);

  for i := 0 to nr-1 do
    for j := 0 to nc-1 do
      c[i,j] := a[i*nc + j];
end;
```

---

```
Var
  MyArray: TMatrix;
Begin
  MakeMat(MyArray,3,3,[  StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:50') ,
                         StrToTime('09:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25') ,
                         StrToTime('10:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25')
                      ]);

end;
```

Comment: Ou seja, não tem como, só dá pra abstrair? Agora não sei se voto pq ñ sei se é verdade, não conheço Delphi suficiente pra isso :(

Comment: Olha eu acredito que não tenha como, o jeito habitual de setar o array seria `MyArray[1,2] := StrToTime('08:25');` mas vamos aguardar se alguém apresenta outra solução :)

Comment: É pelo que vi, é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro o seguinte:

```
var
  MyArray: array of array of TTime;
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, 3, 3);

  MyArray := [[StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:50')],
              [StrToTime('09:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25')],
              [StrToTime('10:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25')]];
```

Você pode explorar as funções intrínsecas que podem ajudar na manipulação de array, especialmente Insert e Delete:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Insert
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Delete

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
var
  MyArray: array of array of TTime;
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, 3, 3);

  Insert([[StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:50')],
          [StrToTime('09:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25')],
          [StrToTime('10:25'), StrToTime('08:25'), StrToTime('08:25')]], MyArray, 1);
```

Mais sobre array:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)